# Referenced DLL not working in Azure build pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, build, msbuild, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

We have upgraded our TFS server to Azure Git, but few old projects are still sitting in TFS. one of my new project needs to reference the dll from the old project from TFS. Everything working ok locally, but Azure build pipeline is failing due to "can't find the reference to dll". How can I reference a dll from TFS project in Azre build pipeline?
This is the path in the project file

```
<ItemGroup>
<Reference Include="Apps.Reserve">
  <HintPath>..\..\..\..\Apps\Reserve\bin\Debug\Apps.Reserve.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

Answer (score 0):

You use MSBuild hardcoded paths which work as a fallback for MSBuild and you shouldn't assume that they will be filled with DLLs on new standalone agents.

You should create **lib** folder from which you will take libraries or create a NuGet feed server (or folder) and setup it up through nuget.config.

From csproj

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="lib\$(TargetFramework)\*.dll" HintPath="%(FilePath)" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Or from nuget.config

```
<config>
    <add key="globalPackagesFolder" value="<your path>" />
</config>
```

It's up to you which approach you will take but from my perspective the best approach is to create your own NuGet Server. Migrate all artifacts there and then migrate projects to Azure Pipelines.

Old TFS "thinking" isn't the best approach to handling feeds.